# systemd service start fails: no service.mount unit

Tags: service, systemd

I wrote a program (node js, on Raspberry Pi) that I can start manually, but not as a systemd service:

```
pi@blueberry ~ $ systemd --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
pi@blueberry ~ $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
pi@blueberry ~ $ sudo systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/rfxtrx.service
Failed to start etc-systemd-system-rfxtrx.service.mount: Unit etc-systemd-system-rfxtrx.service.mount failed to load: No such file or directory.
pi@blueberry ~ $
```

The error message complains that there is no rfxtrx.service.mount unit. Correct. Should there be such unit? The most common suggestion is to daemon-reload; this doid not help. Or as per https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5375 this could be a bug in systemd that was fixed but only in a later systemd version than the one in raspbian (raspbian has version 215).

Is there any other solution than trying to update to a version not supported by the raspbian maintainers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the first problem here is that you're running to start the service name `rfxtrx.service` however systemd is expecting `etc-systemd-system-rfxtrx.service.mount`.

If you are trying to have a systemd mount configuration then your file name should follow the following rule:

> Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they
> control. Example: the mount point /home/lennart must be configured in
> a unit file home-lennart.mount.

So if you were wanting to create a mount point at say `/dir/to/rfxtrx` then the systemd mount file needs to be named `dir-to-rfxtrx.mount`, and it's recommended that it sits in either `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/system/` with the latter directory taking precedence.

If you just wanted to have a service file then enable the unit `systemctl enable rfxtrx.service`.  `systemctl daemon-reload` is used when the unit has already been registered with systemd and requires a reload.

You can check if the service exists with systemd by using the command `systemctl list-units` or `systemctl status rfxtrx.service`.

**The error you have is that you're doing `sudo systemctl start /etc/systemd/system/rfxtrx.service` instead of `sudo systemctl start rfxtrx.service`.**

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your last paragraph solved the issue.

Comment: You may consider putting an emphasis on the last paragraph, the most important part is you can't use the full path

Comment: The last line was the key